# How to remove a version of eclipse from workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I have downloaded a new version of eclipse, but now I can't open it because `there is another version of eclipse attached to the workspace.` I was thinking of deleting the older version but am scared of loosing work. Just wondering what I should do.

Comment: You won't loose any data if you remove/uninstall eclipse. Your projects will be in workspace folder. And now you can have portable version of eclipse. No need to install it.

Comment: It's now telling me it can't delete because it's open in another folder or file. But I can't see it open anywhere, went into task manager and can't see it either. Also restarted laptop. Any ideas?

Comment: Very easy to do thing is, restart your computer and delete it before opening.

Comment: And make sure you do not have your workspace folder inside your eclipse folder.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `.metadata` folder and import your project in your other version of Eclipse.
Make a save of this `.metadata` folder first just in case you need it

Comment: Then delete the old version of eclipse?

Comment: Yes if you don't need it anymore. As Eclipse provide a portable solution (you just need to unzip it and you're good to code), you can have as many Eclipse versions as you want.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @GPRathour download portable version of Eclipse & then import your existing projects into new environment. While doing this uncheck copy projects into workspace option. No need to delete existing. By doing this you can use both Eclipse.

Eclipse uses .metadata folder as well to store internal files and data structures. And many plugins store their settings in here to. Consider the content of this folder as a ‘black box’: so do not change it, do not touch it unless you *really* know what you are doing!